# ERROR: Config value download_clang is not defined in any .rc file

Tags: tensorflow

I tried building tensorflow from source and while doing so I encountered this error please help me.

I have already tried using -c opt instead of --config=opt but it didnt work

(base) rajkirito@rajkirito-Vostro-15-3568:~/tensorflow$ bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

WARNING: The following rc files are no longer being read, please transfer their contents or import their path into one of the standard rc files:
/home/rajkirito/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=80
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from /home/rajkirito/tensorflow/.tf_configure.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/home/rajkirito/anaconda3/bin/python --action_env PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/home/rajkirito/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages --python_path=/home/rajkirito/anaconda3/bin/python --define with_jemalloc=true --define with_gcp_support=true --define with_hdfs_support=true --define with_aws_support=true --define with_kafka_support=true --action_env TF_NEED_OPENCL_SYCL=0 --action_env TF_NEED_CUDA=0 --action_env TF_DOWNLOAD_CLANG=1 --config=download_clang --define grpc_no_ares=true --strip=always
ERROR: Config value download_clang is not defined in any .rc file

Comment: What version of TensorFlow are you trying to build and what version of bazel are you trying to use? Check here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source, under the table "Tested Build Configurations" for the version of bazel to use with the release of TensorFlow you are building.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I resolved that problem. Using inconsistent bazel and Tensorflow versions was the problem.